# hidden post parameter , php curl

Tags: php, http, post, curl

I'm trying to replicate the browser post parameters on http://www.ebayclassifieds.com/m/PostAd?scrid=3465450-2253858851033189948   but for some reasons I can't find where the values for 2 of them are comming from . The parameters are 
btn-previwe-ad.x and 
btn-previwe-ad.y
  but I can't find such as parameters in the html source itself or any hidden value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They represent the x and y position of the mouse pointer relative to the element when clicked, and are added automtically when submitting a form through an `<input type="image">` click:

```
<input name="btn-previwe-ad" ... alt="Preview your ad" type="image">
```

From the [HTML 4.02 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1) ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630871/what-is-input-typeimage-typically-used-for/1630952#1630952)):

> When a pointing device is used to click on the image, the form is submitted and the click coordinates passed to the server. The x value is measured in pixels from the left of the image, and the y value in pixels from the top of the image. The submitted data includes name.x=x-value and name.y=y-value where "name" is the value of the name attribute, and x-value and y-value are the x and y coordinate values, respectively.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. Can you also tell me  the importance/use of those values ? Can they be used to detect "bots"/automated requests ?

Comment: They cannot be used  reliably to detect bots, since they can be easily simulated... I think their only purpose is to act as an image-map. That is you could have a single `<input type="image">` and the server could do a different action according to the area that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

They are the pos x and y of the mouse when you clicked, relative to the clicked button. They are added by default without the need of extra code.